# Access php object value

Tags: php

I have this object i am able to access the name by $object->name but not able to get the starline and endline. I try `$object->starline` it return null.

> PHPParser_Node_Expr_Variable Object ( [subNodes:protected] => Array (
>   [name] => var ) [attributes:protected] => Array ( [startLine] => 2
>   [endLine] => 2 ) )

Comment: They are as stated "protected", so not available to the outside.

Comment: This object doesn't have the property starline!

Comment: but why i am able to get name

Comment: i solved the problem by using print_r($object,true) and just search the start line value from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get $object->name, because the class [PHPParser_NodeAbstract](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/blob/222c9612ab9c65551b7febd38cbb0fa685b0e0db/lib/PHPParser/NodeAbstract.php) has the magic method __get(). 
[PHPParser_Node_Expr_Variable](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/blob/222c9612ab9c65551b7febd38cbb0fa685b0e0db/lib/PHPParser/Node/Expr/Variable.php) extends [PHPParser_Node_Expr](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/blob/222c9612ab9c65551b7febd38cbb0fa685b0e0db/lib/PHPParser/Node/Expr.php) that extends PHPParser_NodeAbstract. So PHPParser_Node_Expr_Variable object has all the methods that these classes have ([Object inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php)).

```
abstract class PHPParser_NodeAbstract implements ...
{
    ....

    public function &__get($name) {
        return $this->subNodes[$name];
    }

    ...

    public function &getAttribute($key, $default = null) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $this->attributes)) {
            return $default;
        } else {
            return $this->attributes[$key];
        }
    }
}
```

And you don't get $object->starline, because there is no such property "starline" in the array subNodes. 
But if you look at the method getAttribute(), you will understand that this code has to work.

```
$object->getAttribute('startLine');
```

Comment: thanks getAttribute solved the problem.